# No method lazy() found for enum Result when working with Polars dataframes

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I'm learning Rust and decided to play with Polars dataframes and getting some errors that I can't understand. The code is simply meant to create a dataframe and then add a new column as the sum of two existing ones:

```
fn main() {

    let _df = DataFrame::default();

    let df= df!(
        "a" => &[1, 2, 3, 4],
        "b" => &[2, 3, 4, 5],
    );

    println!("{:#?}", df);
    
    let df = df.lazy()
        .with_column(
            col("a") + col("b"),
            "c"
        )
        .collect()
        .unwrap();
}
```

It fails at the call to the `lazy()` method:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `lazy` found for enum `Result` in the current scope
  --> src/bin/dataframes.rs:16:17
   |
16 |     let df = df.lazy()
   |                 ^^^^ method not found in `Result<DataFrame, PolarsError>`
   |
note: the method `lazy` exists on the type `polars::prelude::DataFrame`
  --> /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/polars-lazy-0.35.4/src/frame/mod.rs:45:5
   |
45 |     fn lazy(self) -> LazyFrame;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: consider using `Result::expect` to unwrap the `polars::prelude::DataFrame` value, panicking if the value is a `Result::Err`
```

I see the compiler is giving me some potentially useful suggestions, but I don't understand how or where to use `Result::expect` to unwrap Dataframe value.

I understand that the idea is that `out` may be either a DataFrame or an error so do I need to add some `match` construction here?

**EDIT**
Ok, I figured out what to do here but I'm confused because I haven't seen any of this in the official documentation:

```
    let df = df.expect("").lazy()
        .with_column(
            (col("a") + col("b")).alias("c")
        )
        .collect()
        .unwrap();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[polars lazy documentation](https://docs.rs/polars-lazy/0.35.4/polars_lazy/index.html)

The official document does say `df!` macro needs to be unwrapped. Though it doesn't explain why.

Here's the example code in the documentation:

```rust
 let df = df! {
     "column_a" => &[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     "column_b" => &["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
 }.unwrap();
```

You should check out the [official rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html) for more explanation on the `Result` type.

But for a brief explanation: The `Result<T, E>` type is returned when a function or macro like `df!` could evaluate to an error. The enum `Result` is used to represent that. The user must handle both possibilities with `match` or other methods.

`result.expect("error message")` and `result.unwrap()` are used to directly extract the `T` from `Result::Ok(T)` and crash the program if the result value is a `Result::Err(E)`. This is done usually for convenience during development, but is not recommended for release.

Answer (score 2):

Because `DataFrame` creation is fallible (what if the columns passed don't all have the same length?), `df!` returns a `Result<DataFrame, PolarsError>`. You need to handle that before getting the `DataFrame` inside (like any other `Result` in Rust).

The docs [here](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/frame/struct.DataFrame.html) show how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent panicking on `Err` variant, you can use

```rust
df.map(DataFrame::lazy)
```

to prevent unwrapping the result